# Is it [turn-by-turn]'s turn to get burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I believe the tag [turn-by-turn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turn-by-turn) should be burninated.

It fails all the preliminary checks before burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. It is often used to describe certain (real-life) navigation APIs, but it is ambiguous as to which API. Of the 21 questions, one of them is asking about role-playing games and one is looking for the `zip` function.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Well, it can be I guess.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. The questions are about the turn-by-turn API **of a specific API**.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Definitely not. It can refer to Mapbox or [HERE Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_WeGo#HERE_Maps) (at least).

Comment: [Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/turn-by-turn-navigation/): *"Turn-by-turn navigation, also referred to as active guidance, ... a typical navigation experience: a user receives turn-by-turn instructions as they progress along the route. If a trip session is running and a route is selected, the Navigation SDK goes into an internal active guidance state."*

Comment: Plenty of `mapbox-*` tags between `-api-directons` and `-navigation` to likely retag the useful questions in this bunch.

Comment: With only 21 questions to process, once approval is given, it should be simple to process (one person, two at most, could complete it in under an hour).

Comment: In the absence of context, I would consider that _turn by turn_ is not on-topic for this site.

Comment: With only 21 questions, I don't think this requires a full burnination procedure. As said by Jonathan, this is a two-person job at most.

Comment: @Mast: In which case we need an expert in navigation to weigh in. I won't miss the tag.

Comment: Truly a solution in search of a problem.